# What is the sort criteria for 'argument field' in dxChart?

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, devexpress, datasource

I am working in a chart syde-by-syde bar, when i finished I saw order of my 'argument field' is wrong, i am sending in right order, but chart is shown disordered.

I haven't been found nothing in documentation about how to sort this field. I will be so grateful if someone knows the trick for fix it.

Here is my chart and its datasource:

```
var dataSource = [
    { state: "01-Aug-2017", Juan_Sebastián: 7,María_Alejandra: 3,José_Tomás: 8,},
    { state: "02-Aug-2017",Juan_Sebastián: 1,María_Alejandra: 2, },
    { state: "03-Aug-2017",María_Alejandra: 3,Juan_Sebastián: 2,José_Tomás: 4,},
    { state: "04-Aug-2017",José_Tomás: 2,Juan_Sebastián: 4,},                                                                                                 
    { state: "08-Aug-2017",José_Tomás: 1, },
    { state: "09-Aug-2017",María_Alejandra: 1,José_Tomás: 2,},                                                                                                                                             
    { state: "10-Aug-2017",Juan_Sebastián: 1,},                                                                                                                 
    { state: "14-Aug-2017",José_Tomás: 1,María_Alejandra: 2,},                                                                                                            
    { state: "15-Aug-2017",Juan_Sebastián: 1,},                                                                                                                   
    { state: "16-Aug-2017",Juan_Sebastián: 1,José_Tomás: 2, },                                                                                                    
    { state: "17-Aug-2017",María_Alejandra: 1,},                                                                                                                   
 ];

$("#bar-2").dxChart({
  equalBarWidth: false,
  dataSource: dataSource,
  commonSeriesSettings: {
     argumentField: "state",
     type: "bar" 
},
  series: [
{ valueField: "Juan_Sebastián", name: "Juan Sebastián"},
{ valueField: "María_Alejandra", name: "María Alejandra"},
{ valueField: "José_Tomás", name: "José Tomás"},

 ],
 legend: {
   verticalAlignment: "bottom",
   horizontalAlignment: "center"},
 title: "Cantidad de casos por abogado"
                                    });
                                });
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

I really don't know why is changing the order of original dataSource.
Many Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your chart and datasource code above in jsFiddle and here in code snippet, everything looks correct.

https://jsfiddle.net/jmarking/089j1hrs/

```js
var dataSource = [{
    state: "01-Aug-2017",
    Juan_Sebastián: 7,
    María_Alejandra: 3,
    José_Tomás: 8,
  },
  {
    state: "02-Aug-2017",
    Juan_Sebastián: 1,
    María_Alejandra: 2,
  },
  {
    state: "03-Aug-2017",
    María_Alejandra: 3,
    Juan_Sebastián: 2,
    José_Tomás: 4,
  },
  {
    state: "04-Aug-2017",
    José_Tomás: 2,
    Juan_Sebastián: 4,
  },
  {
    state: "08-Aug-2017",
    José_Tomás: 1,
  },
  {
    state: "09-Aug-2017",
    María_Alejandra: 1,
    José_Tomás: 2,
  },
  {
    state: "10-Aug-2017",
    Juan_Sebastián: 1,
  },
  {
    state: "14-Aug-2017",
    José_Tomás: 1,
    María_Alejandra: 2,
  },
  {
    state: "15-Aug-2017",
    Juan_Sebastián: 1,
  },
  {
    state: "16-Aug-2017",
    Juan_Sebastián: 1,
    José_Tomás: 2,
  },
  {
    state: "17-Aug-2017",
    María_Alejandra: 1,
  },
];

$("#bar-2").dxChart({
  equalBarWidth: false,
  dataSource: dataSource,
  commonSeriesSettings: {
    argumentField: "state",
    type: "bar"
  },
  series: [{
      valueField: "Juan_Sebastián",
      name: "Juan Sebastián"
    },
    {
      valueField: "María_Alejandra",
      name: "María Alejandra"
    },
    {
      valueField: "José_Tomás",
      name: "José Tomás"
    },

  ],
  legend: {
    verticalAlignment: "bottom",
    horizontalAlignment: "center"
  },
  title: "Cantidad de casos por abogado"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/17.1.6/css/dx.common.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/17.1.6/css/dx.light.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/17.1.6/js/dx.all.js"></script>
<div id="bar-2"></div>
```

Comment: It is very baffling, I still cant understand why my chart looks bad, could be a bug in my library?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your project as whole.  If you copied their scripts locally, you could try things like using the CDN services as I did to ensure there wasn't an error copying, or accidental change to one of their files locally.  I would check the order of your scripts - maybe you have a dependency being called after; this would likely show up in the console log.  Speaking of the console, are you getting any console errors?  You might also check for conflicting issues between other libraries - for instance, if you're also using D3.js, they may not play nicely together.

Comment: You might also want to double check versions of libraries.  Above you'll see I'm using jQuery 3.1 and dx version 17.1.6.  If you are using different versions, you'll want to check compatibility between them.